# Establishing a Persistent Connection to Firebase Using TCP / IP on the Backend Instead of Using RESTFul HTTP Requests?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently using PHP / CURL on the back-end to update values in Firebase.  We use Firebase primarily as a JavaScript layer so we can show browser and app clients real time status progression of jobs we process.

We've gotten to the point where we're doing quite a bit of status updating using CURL from our back-end and I feel we are close to the threshold where establishing a persistent connection between Firebase and our server would be more efficient than opening and closing dozens of HTTP requests per minute.

Is there anyway to do this with Firebase right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase has server-side SDKs for Java and Node.js. If you can't use those, the REST API is your only alternative.

If you'd like to *listen* for data over REST, you can use Firebase's REST Streaming API, which uses a long-lived HTTP connection to return a stream of events. It is similar to the Firebase SDKs, but it can only attach a single listener per connection, and you'll still need separate requests for write operations.

That last part seems to the crux of your problem. So I'm afraid there really aren't any alternatives from using the SDKs as I mentioned. In my testing using HTTP requests for frequent small (although in my case admittedly *read*) operations was quite fast.